# How do proponents of the “Framework hypothesis” hold to their view when God used the word “Yom” instead of “Olam” in Genesis 1?

Tags: genesis, creation

Knowing that the Hebrew word generally used for day is yom, and the word for eternal/ or Age (Olam) isn’t used, how do the proponents of the framework hypothesis hold their view?

Is God too slow for 6 days of creation?

**Q: How do proponents of the “Framework hypothesis” hold to their view when God used the word “Yom” instead of “Olam” in Genesis 1?**

Definition linked from Wikipedia:

> “The **framework interpretation** is a description of the structure of the
> first chapter of the Book of Genesis, the Genesis creation narrative.
> Biblical scholars and theologians present the structure as evidence
> that Gen. 1 presents a **symbolic**, rather than **literal**, presentation of
> creation. Wikipedia“

For scripture reflection:

> “Remember the former things long past, For I am God, and there is no
> other; I am God, and there is no one like Me, Declaring the end from
> the beginning, And from ancient times things which have not been done,
> Saying, ‘**My purpose will be established, And I will accomplish all
> My good pleasure**’;” ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭46:9-10‬ ‭

Genesis isn’t normally regarded as a book of symbolism like Revelation, so where do they assume such Exegesis?

Comment: I don't understand what issue you are seeing. The framework view is that Genesis 1 is largely metaphorical. Why would the absence of a word be at all relevant?

Comment: @curiousdannii In seeking to establish how they hold their view, I find it confusing that they interpret day as “age” or “sequence” or whatever term they use.  Hence the question.

Comment: And how is the absence of Olam relevant? Metaphors don't have to be explained literally in the same text!

Comment: @Cork88 I think a question something like "If by 'day' God meant a large unit of time, why didn't He use 'olam' in Genesis 1, according to proponents of the framework interpretation" is a good question. However, I think you're bringing in ontological issues that don't need to be raised - I'm actually not sure how God being omnipotent maps onto your question, so perhaps you can fill out the implicit argument if applicable here.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Made some major edits then.  Thanks for the elaboration.

Comment: @curiousdannii The absence of Olam is relevant because the use of a metaphor in Genesis 1 is unlikely when it comes to the “days” of creation, “the evening and the morning were the third day” for example.  What is evening and morning signify?  24 hours.  So I am curious why they assume “ages” as opposed to “single day”.

Comment: Here is a link to the Wikipedia definition of the framework hypothesis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework_interpretation_(Genesis)

Answer (score 1):

I know young earth creationists often claim the word "yom" refers only to literal 24-hour days, but this isn't true. This is the *usual* usage, but it is also used metaphorically to refer to a time period, much like the word "day" in English. Indeed, in [Genesis 2:4](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/2-4.htm), the same exact word "yom" is used to refer to the entire period of creation. If we believe that the Bible does not contradict itself, then we must say that at least one usage of "yom" in Gen 1-2 is not referring to a 24-hour period.

I haven't really decided for myself where I stand on this question. I'm a firm believer in the historical accuracy of the Bible. I'm not really sold on the framework hypothesis, but I would not say it's obviously wrong either.

I would also point out that modern science has proven that the length of a period of time is not absolute, but rather is determined by the reference frame of the observer. Even if we are to take Genesis 1 as absolutely historical, there is no human reference frame, and thus no reason to assume the timescale is amenable to a hypothetical human observer who didn't exist yet. Even if we take it as given that "yom" in Genesis 1 is always meant to refer to a 24-hour period, who is measuring that 24-hour period? There is nothing in the text to say that, if we had taken the measurements from an earth-based reference frame, we wouldn't have said the creation period took billions of years. The text doesn't say, nor even have details to imply, what reference frame the 6-day timeline is meant to be measured against. Whether we take the framework hypothesis or not, claiming the universe is billions of years old (from a certain reference frame), does not contradict the text. It only contradicts some assumptions that we commonly use to fill in details which God decided to omit.

Comment: Given the fact that time is determined by reference frame and the text doesn't give us one to us for Gen. 1, the relevant question is not "how long would a hypothetical human observe the creation period to be?" but rather "why did God choose a reference frame such that the creation period is six days?" I guess, if you don't admit any old-earth possibility, this is equivalent to "why would God choose to create in a period of six days?" In either case, the answers are going to be the same, and we are both reading the text as a true creation account. I see no need for fighting on this issue.

Comment: "I know young earth creationists often claim the word "yom" refers only to literal 24-hour days," That's not true. That's a misrepresentation made by opponents of YEC. Any YEC text on the topic of *yom* will readily explain that the word has several meanings on various contexts.

Comment: Hi Dark Malthorp, this answer reads more like a thread on a forum than an answer to a question.  The idea for this site is that if a questions asks something like "How do proponents .... " you answer as a proponent (or ignore the question),  if the question needs improving or clarification it's best to do that by commenting on the question; otherwise you'd have to edit your answer to meet what the real question is.  Kind of a moot point since this question is now closed though.

Comment: Do you moderators want to tell me why my question lacks clarity?  It makes no sense to close it, at least according to my current knowledge.